# Grounding a GFCI outlet by connecting the receptacle's grounding screw to a metal box

Tags: electrical, gfci

Would connecting the grounding screw of a single-location GFCI receptacle to a metal box with an armored cable leading to it serve as equipment ground, making the "no E.G." sticker unnecessary?

Comment: It will depend on the exact type of cable in place. Some "armored" (flexible metal tubing) cables can have their shell used as a grounding path, some cannot. Check the cable for markings.

Comment: Please provide pics of the cable in question and the wiring where it enters the box, as well as any labeling you can find on the cable or individual wires.

Answer (score 2):

If the box is properly grounded, you may not even need to connect a wire to the ground terminal on the receptacle.

Many receptacles are self-grounding - once you screw the receptacle to a properly grounded box, the receptacle itself is now grounded. IMHO, it's well worth the extra buck or two to get one of these as they usually also come with side-clamps for the hot & neutral wires making the whole wiring process much easier.